# Javascript two arrays, values less than 20 from one array delete the same index numbers from second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var keyTimes = new Array(1,2,3,4,5);
var keyValues = new Array (30,10,5,25,15);
```

I want to find numbers less then 20 in `keyValues` and delete the same index numbers from `keyTimes` array.

So, the `keyTimes` array should look like this:

```
keyTimes = (1,4);
```

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given both Arrays are the exact same length:

```js
let keyTimes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    keyValues = [30, 10, 5, 25, 15];

keyTimes = keyTimes.filter((v, i) => keyValues[i] >= 20 );

console.log(keyTimes) // [1, 4]
```

the above uses **ES6** (ES2015) [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with implied return,

**ES5 (*ECMA-262***)

```js
var keyTimes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var keyValues = [30, 10, 5, 25, 15];

keyTimes = keyTimes.filter(function(v, i) {
 return keyValues[i] >= 20 ;
});

console.log(keyTimes) // [1, 4]
```

#### Using `for` loop:

```js
var keyTimes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var keyValues = [30, 10, 5, 25, 15];

for (var i = keyTimes.length; i > 0; i--)  {
  if (keyValues[i] < 20) keyTimes.splice(i, 1);
}

console.log(keyTimes); // [1, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Roko. I'm working on a script for After Effects. I've tried filter before but it's not working in Extendscript. I don't know if it's possible to do this with for loop?

Comment: The primary reason that some of those functions do not exist, is because ExtendScript is based on the ECMA-262 standard. Very old Javascript, and I believe not all of it is implemented.

Comment: @Aleksandar filter() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition so you should be OK with it, beside that you can use a classic `function` instead of Arrow function

Comment: Thank you Roko, but that's not working either. I've came up with this solution:

Comment: var keyValues = [30, 10, 5, 25, 15],
    keyTimes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];    

for (var i = keyTimes.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
    if(keyValues[i]<20){
   keyTimes.splice(keyTimes[i-1],1);
}
    alert(keyTimes);

Comment: And I'm getting keyTimes = (1,4);  But in real world I have keyTimes like: 0.3333333, 2.145648, 4.41523456 etc. And with those numbers I don't get the right result. What could be a problem? Thanks Roko

Comment: @Aleksandar there should be no problem by using floats and `< 20` ... Are zou sure those are really floated numbers rather than Strings `"0.333"`?

Comment: Those are arrays Roko. I'm getting keyTimes every keyframe from After Effects. And those are in seconds, so if project has 30 frames per seconds it will be like this: 1/30, 2/30, 3/30, 4/30, 5/30 etc. So I'm getting some funky results. I think I have to find the index numbers but indexOf() method doesn't work either.

Comment: For example if my keyTimes look like this:   keyTimes = [0.03333333333, 0.06666666666, 0.1, 0.13333333, 0.16666666666];   I'm getting keyTimes=(0.13333333, 0.16666666666); the last two numbers instead of first and fourth number keyTimes=(0.03333333333,0.13333333);

Comment: That's it Roko, this code works. Thank you so much for you time. Appreciate that.